# xUbuntu USB boot

Tags: boot, usb, xubuntu, bios, sony

I just created an xUbuntu boot USB key using Universal-USB-Installer.

My Sony Viao has a USB port but xUbuntu did not load when I powered the computer.

I learnt I have to configure my bios to allow loading from usb but I don't seem to have the relevant option.

In the boot section of my bios, I have the following:

- Optical drive
- Floppy disk drive
- Hard disk drive
- Network

As my computer does not have a floppy drive so I moved it to the top of the list, saved and restarted but xUbuntu still does not load from my USB stick.

Can anyone help, please?

UPDATE:
It seems none of the options allow for booting from cd either

Comment: What is your Sony Vaio model?

Comment: Not all computers can boot from USB. Perhaps my Sony Viao can't.

Comment: @TungTran: the model is PCG-7AIM

Answer (score -1):

Look around in the settings for some option like `Allow booting from External USB`. Some systems disable this option for security reasons.

Also, the best approach if that fails is to create a LiveCD and boot.

Answer (score -1):

Access your BIOS Settings, go into **Boot** menu and then change **Boot Mode** from **EUFI** to **Legacy**.

Comment: No boot mode option :-(

Comment: It's bad luck! :(